# MYSQL / PHP TWO Multiselect Dropdown Filters (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, filtering

The errors I am getting are the following: (Also i am echoing the query statement)

**Notice**: Array to string conversion in /home/fanati10/public_html/wp-content/themes/digital-pro/page-nflwranalyzer.php on line 75

**Notice**: Array to string conversion in /home/fanati10/public_html/wp-content/themes/digital-pro/page-nflwranalyzer.php on line 79 
*SELECT * FROM WR_TeamAnalyzer WHERE TMID = ? AND WKID = ?*

HERE IS MY php file

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
      require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/config/config.php' );
      if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
        $nflposs = "";
        foreach($_POST['check'] as $val => $text_field) {
          $nflposs.=$text_field.", ";
       }
          $nflpossint = rtrim($nflposs, ', ');
          $nflposs = explode(',', $nflpossint);
          $placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($nflposs)), ', ');
          $filter[] = "TMID = $placeholders";
          $values[] = $nflpossint;
      }
       if(isset($_POST['wk'])) {
        $wkid = "";
        foreach($_POST['wk'] as $val => $text_field) {
          $wkid.=$text_field.", ";
       }
          $wkidint = rtrim($wkid, ', ');
          $wkid = explode(',', $wkidint);
          $placeholders2 = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($wkid)), ', ');
          $filter[] = "WKID = $placeholders2";
          $values[] = $wkidint;
      }
      $sql="SELECT * FROM WR_TeamAnalyzer WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $filter);
      echo ($sql);
      $selectStmt = $dbcon->prepare($sql);
      $selectStmt->execute($values);
      $rows = $selectStmt->fetchAll();
  $tableContent = '';
  foreach ($rows as $row){
    $tableContent = $tableContent.'<tr>'.
```

Comment: when i print the Arrays i get
print_r($filter);  Array ( [0] => TMID = ? [1] => WKID = ?, ? ) 

print_r($values);  Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 3, 4 )

Answer (score 1):

When you use `=` in a query it will expect a string. But you are passing an Array (`values`) in parameters. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here but if you want to check in an Array, change these two lines in your code as below:

```
TMID IN $placeholders
WKID IN $placeholders2
```

Your final query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM WR_TeamAnalyzer WHERE TMID IN (?) AND WKID IN (?)
```

Comment: what you posted still only allows to filter by one option per column... so basically based on your answer the query would look like this ......................................... $sql="SELECT * FROM WR_TeamAnalyzer WHERE TMID IN (1) AND WKID IN (2)";

Comment: What i want is the query to filter multiple selections per dropdown.....Here I manually typed the query how I want it to filter........................................... $sql="SELECT * FROM WR_TeamAnalyzer WHERE TMID IN (1, 2) AND WKID IN (2, 3)";

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

change:

```
$filter[] = "TMID IN $placeholders";
$values = $nflpossint;
```

&

```
$filter[] = "WKID IN $placeholders2"; 
$values2 = $wkidint;
```

&

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM WR_TeamAnalyzer WHERE TMID IN ($values) AND WKID IN ($values2)";
$selectStmt = $dbcon->prepare($sql);
$selectStmt->execute();
```

Comment: Dont even need the $filter[](s)